# Mapping api for my application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, google-maps, mapping, bing-api

I am writing a c# silverlight application which displays points onto a map.

Basically what needs to happen is this:
1. I have a dataset of locations. I need to find for example the ten nearest locations from my dataset (of my current location), and/or, search a location like 'london' and give me the nearest locations from there in a XML file I can read.
2. I then need to use my an API I have access to which requests information about these ten locations and returns data via a rest interface.

Point number 2 is fine. But what is the best way of going about point number 1. Do people upload there dataset to a mapping API like bing or google and let them return the required results if you give them your current location or search for a specified place?

Many thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up your own database?  If so, you can look at something like PostgreSQL with the [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) extension or, if you have a license for this, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Spatial.  Both of these databases can handle spatial queries. You can write a SQL query that basically uses the current location as an input and then selects the 10 closest points/features to that location.

You could also try something like uploading your data to [MapQuest's](http://www.mapquest.com) Data Manager (part of their [Developer Services](http://developer.mapquest.com/)) to use their [Search API](http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/) to search your data table in the Data Manager and return features as needed.  You can specify XML as a format for your results.  I think a benefit of using their Search API is that it can do various kinds of searches, like radius, rectangle, and it can even search along a route line.  So for instance, if you had a route plotted between two locations, it can find everything within a distance of that route.  A spatial database could also do this, but it might be harder to set up, depending on your level of experience.

It just depends on how much you want to do yourself and how large of a dataset you have.  Hope this helps to point you in the right direction!